# Are 24-year old women afraid of Rush Limbaugh?

Tags: liberalism, conservatism

Rush Limbaugh continually jokes on his show lately about how 24-year women are afraid of him. Apparently, some university study or liberal news mouthpiece or someone has an article that claims that specifically 24-year old women get scared of his voice when Rush gets passionate about the subject he's talking about. Presumably, an attempt to muzzle him.

One of the things I love about Rush is that he ridicules the ridiculous. He points out these crazy ideas that the left gets, and makes fun of them. But he doesn't mention the source of the original article he is making fun of. Can anyone point me to the source of his joke?

Comment: I think it isn't based on a study. It is related to the fact that Obama said that the Republican party is afraid of Rush, the fact that 60% of Millennials ((18-29 year olds, with 23/24 being right in the middle) voted for Obama and are now losing faith in the country. I am pretty sure it is a mashup of multiple stories, but you would have to be a regular listener to piece all the inside joke pieces together.

Comment: No, he keeps saying that specifically 24 year old women are afraid. That was part of the ridiculousness of the original story. What you are saying is what you would expect in a scientific study: That a RANGE of people had a certain reaction. This story specifically cited 24-year old women, not 23, not 25, just 24. That is what Rush keeps harping on.

Comment: Journalistic license. Next question?

Comment: "No, <blah>"" I never said that he **didn't** specifically say 24 yo women. Rush is a comedian, and for comedic effect, 24 yo women is funnier than both sexes ages 18-29. You can make jokes about 24 yo women being scared out of their panties by Rush, so hopefully there are some millennial men near by to take advantage of that fact, (where the more accurate claim is not funny)

Comment: Alright, I will try again. The STORY that Rush is making fun of, specifically mentioned 24-year old women. He is making fun of it in part because an allegedly scientific study was able to narrow it down to 24-year old women. It is not a mashup of multiple stories, it is one specific study. He has done similar things in the past, where one column or one article is so outrageous, he references it constantly. Anyway, can anyone point me to the original story?

Comment: Asking us to fact check Rush Limbaugh's "jokes" seems to not be the best fit for SE.

Comment: But to answer the question, it looks like the direct quote is "I've been told that I scare and frighten 24-year-old women." I'd say "I've been told" is a phrase sufficiently vague enough that's it's pretty much anecdotal, at best and likely just plain artistic license. http://www.rushlimbaugh.com/daily/2013/04/26/this_is_how_it_starts_one_uconn_student_says_new_husky_logo_promotes_rape

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this recurring theme evolved from the [Sandra Fluke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Limbaugh%E2%80%93Sandra_Fluke_controversy) story, over which Limbaugh took a bit of heat due to his harsh language.  Fluke was 30 at the time, but Limbaugh often used Fluke as a proxy for other female students whom he argued were asking the government to subsidize their sexual preferences and associated lifestyle (other graduate students would more likely be in their early-to-mid twenties, which would fit the meme).

Comment: Is it really a 'meme' if it's just him? :)

Comment: @DA.: I qualified it as a "Rush" meme - he tends to take certain stories and remix them into a lot of his shows.  Whenever he says something like "for all you out there in Rio-Linda, ...", he's about to explain one of the memes of the show.

Comment: Well, I was trying to poke fun of the fact that a meme requires more than one person for it to exist. If Rush is the only one repeating it, then it's not a meme. It's just Rush.

Comment: @DA.: No poking fun, because we hate fun at SE ;-)  Maybe "recurring theme" would be a better term.